# CSS conditions - if element has both classes

Tags: css

How to make conditions in a CSS stylesheet?

Here I got a stylesheet.. But if the `div.menu_active` is added on an element the class has to behave like its hovered? How can you do that?

Or is there an even better way to contruct the stylesheet for this solution?

```
<div class="menu">menu</div>
<div class="menu menu_active">menu</div> // has to behave like menu:hover

<div class="menu_green">menu</div>
<div class="menu_green menu_active">menu</div> // has to behave like menu_green:hover

div.menu {
background:url('menu_opacity50.png');
}

div.menu_green {
background:url('menu_green_opacity50.png');
}

div.menu_active {
}

div.menu:hover {
background:url('menu_opacity100.png');
}

div.menu_green:hover {
background:url('menu_green_opacity100.png');
}
```

Comment: the code you have shown, seems absolutely fine. What problems are you having ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this is what you need:

```
div.menu:hover, .menu.menu_active {
    background:url('menu_opacity100.png');
}    
div.menu_green:hover, .menu_green.menu_active {
    background:url('menu_green_opacity100.png');
}
```

`.menu.menu_active` will select elements that have *both* of the listed classes, such as `<div class="menu menu_active">`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might mean this:

```
div.menu.menu_active,
div.menu:hover {
    background:url('menu_opacity100.png');
}

div.menu_green.menu_active,
div.menu_green:hover {
    background:url('menu_green_opacity100.png');
}
```

Comment: the site is made with js and is using #hash.. so can't use `active`

Comment: I don't understand. In that case, can't you just add the class `active` via jQuery then?

Comment: Oh I see, misunderstanding. I forgot to include the `menu_` in the class. Amended now.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to do this

```
div.menu {
    background:url('menu_opacity50.png');
}

div.menu_green {
    background:url('menu_green_opacity50.png');
}

div.menu.menu_active {
    background:url('menu_opacity100.png');
}

div.menu_green.menu_active {
    background:url('menu_green_opacity100.png');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Overlay the hover element exactly over normal state and hide it (display:none) then use JS/jQuery to toggle the display.